# saltstack how to verify variable from jinja, result wrong from if statement

Tags: linux, jinja2, salt-stack

I was trying to write a state to set patching status, the if statement based on a result from a cmd.run, I checked the result that it should be 'No', meaning no available patches, but my state return said otherwise.

I checked:-

```
# salt 'minion1' cmd.run "yum --security check-update | grep 'for security'| awk '{print \$1}'"
minion1:
    No
#
```

My state file:-

```
{% set minion = salt['cmd.run']("yum --security check-update | grep 'for security'| awk '{print \$1}'") %}

{% if minion|float == 'No' %}
no_patch:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "no update"

{% else %}
patch_pls:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "Patch please"

{% endif %}
```

my run result:-

```
minion1:
----------
          ID: patch_pls
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: echo "Patch please"
      Result: True
     Comment: Command "echo "Patch please"" run
     Started: 12:22:10.894779
    Duration: 10.047 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              pid:
                  19397
              retcode:
                  0
              stderr:
              stdout:
                  Patch please

Summary for minion1
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:  10.047 ms
```

Been spending hours trying to figure it out but just feeling defeated and frustrated right now.

You're my last hope. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using the `|float` filter in comparison for `if` statement?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking, I wasn't sure about the |float, it didn't change much even if I remove the |float

Comment: Are you **sure** that you get a "No" from the manual invocation?  The ``\``in `awk '{print \$1}'` is a syntax error ...  that said:  you don't need any of the grepping and awking, just check the return value.  If it's not `0` there are security patches or another problems that should draw your attention.  If you don't care about other problems think again about what @seshadri_c asked you ...

Comment: The return will only be "No" if there's no security patches available, meaning they're patched.  and Yes, I have double checked the return manually. Thanks.

Comment: man..i'm so stuck on this one.

Comment: I would use one of the [`pkg.list_` functions](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.yumpkg.html) and filter it in Jinja.

Comment: Thank you @OrangeDog, I've looked it up and unfortunately, we only care about "Security" patches, and I can't seems to find that in the pkg.list_functions.

Comment: @Atlas that's `list_patches` isn't it? As opposed to `list_upgrades`.